# Google gson.toJson(List) returning response as string instead of array

Tags: java, gson, arrays, json

I am trying to use JsonObject to convert the java object to String. Following is the code that i am using to add the properties :

```
    JsonObject jsonObject = new JsonObject();
    jsonObject.addProperty("id", favoriteWrapper.getId());
    jsonObject.addProperty("menuitemid", favoriteWrapper.getMenuItemId());
    jsonObject.addProperty("displayname", favoriteWrapper.getDisplayName());
    jsonObject.addProperty("description", favoriteWrapper.getDescription());
    jsonObject.addProperty("alias", favoriteWrapper.getAlias());
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    jsonObject.addProperty("condiments", gson.toJson(favoriteWrapper.getCondiments()));
```

Here the last property condiments is a list of Long values and following is the response retrieved:

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "menuitemid": 1,
        "displayname": "Ham",
        "description": "Ham",
        "alias": "Ham",
        "condiments": "[1,8,34,2,6]"
    }
]
```

Expected output is as following which is different for condiments:

```
   [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "menuitemid": 1,
            "displayname": "Ham",
            "description": "Ham",
            "alias": "Ham",
            "condiments": [1,8,34,2,6]
        }
    ]
```

What should I do to get the condiments as JSON array rather than String ?

Comment: Your solution look contradictory, why do you use both JsonObject and Gson? And besides that I think the problem is in your understanding of the library, not in the output of the code

Comment: [Gson.toJson(Object)](http://google-gson.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/gson/docs/javadocs/com/google/gson/Gson.html#toJson-java.lang.Object-) returns a `String`, yes as expected

Comment: you are asking gson.toJson() to convert the array in a string. jsonObject.addProperty() adds the string. it doesn't know its an array, and puts quotes around it like any other string it would add. As gerrytan suggests, the solution may require sticking to one library.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the answer to my problem. I used JsonArray and JsonPrimitive to achieve the required response:

```
      JsonObject jsonObject = new JsonObject();
      jsonObject.addProperty("id", favoriteWrapper.getId());
      jsonObject.addProperty("menuitemid", favoriteWrapper.getMenuItemId());
      jsonObject.addProperty("displayname", favoriteWrapper.getDisplayName());
      jsonObject.addProperty("description", favoriteWrapper.getDescription());
      jsonObject.addProperty("alias", favoriteWrapper.getAlias());

      JsonArray condiments = new JsonArray();
         for (Long condimentId : favoriteWrapper.getCondiments()) {
                condiments.add(new JsonPrimitive(condimentId));
         }

      jsonObject.add("condiments", condiments);
      jsonObjects.add(jsonObject);
```